# Web scraping using lxml

Tags: python, pandas, xpath, lxml

I'm very new to python. I'm trying to scrape an html table
from https://tshf.sas.com/techsup/download/hotfix/HF2/E1Y_r64.html#E1Y015
with the xpath .//table[contains(., 'E1Y015 ')]

It is basically the only big table that you can find in that url

Can someone help me with the code to scrape data from this particular html table to a python dataframe using lxml or any other effective method? I want the colspan to be handled as well.

I tried read_html but it doesnt handle colspan effectively. Any help is much appreciated.

Below is my code where I used read_html

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("xxxxx.html")
#the above html file has some urls under which the html tables that I need to scrape are present
#Im taking those elements that have the hyperlinks here
links = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[1]')
for l in links:
    #below I'm taking the value of href attribute for the hyperlinks
    url = str(l.get_attribute('href'))
    #I'm doing some manipulations to locate the right table
    spl_char='#'
    r = url.partition(spl_char)[2] + '\s+'
    all_tables = pd.read_html(url,match=r,keep_default_na=False)
    df = all_tables[0]
    #finally Im converting it to csv. Ignore "arc" variable. It does not concern my problem here. It is just for the filename
    with open('./%s.csv' %arc[i], 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n')
    df.to_csv('./%s.csv' %arc[i] , mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

The csv file creates duplicate values in adjacent cells of a row if there is column span. After reading through some stackoverflow posts and other forums, I understood that it can be better handled by lxml. I referred to Python for data analysis by Wes McKinney for XML and HTML: Web Scraping

I saw the below code to get all tables and then he uses table index to get specific ones

```
tables = doc.findall('.//table')
calls = tables[9]
puts = tables[13]
```

I cannot use table index in my case as I have to go through multiple similar urls and the required table is not in the same position all the time. Instead, I can get the required table using the xpath like this - .//table[contains(., 'E1Y015 ')]
As I am new to coding and I am doing this as a simplification of a mundane task that we do, I need help in figuring this out.

[example screenshot of the current output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVvG2.png)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. We will gladly help you, as long as you show us that you tried to solve the problem yourself: show us your coding efforts.

Comment: That's fair :) Sorry about that. I added the code now.